# Unable to send mail through mandrill in rails application deployed on Google compute engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, google-compute-engine

I have a rails app deployed on Google Compute Engine.
Everything works fine and it requires to send mail in application so I follow [this](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21738467-Using-Mandrill-s-SMTP-integration-with-Web-Frameworks) link for sending mail it works on local but I am unable to send mail through mandrill smtp settings.

I always get **Timeout::Error (execution expired)** error message, what could be the reason??

Any idea on what's could be the problem?

Comment: Don't you mean Google Compute Engine instead of Google App Engine?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/jlberglund/mandrill_dm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Compute Engine does not support [outbound TCP connections on port 25](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/sending-mail). Instead you can use port 2525 that Mandrill also supports.